# Google Maps Embed API error: "... Invalid request. Unexpected parameter 't'."

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-embed

After generating an embedded google maps iframe, my site is showing the following error message within the frame:

> The Google Maps API server rejected your request. Invalid request.
>   Unexpected parameter 't'.

The HTML code for the frame appears valid:

```
<iframe height="400" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=40.750504,-73.99343899999997&amp;key=my_key" width="400"></iframe>
```

This is the python (web2py) code that's being used to generate the iframe ([IFRAME()](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/05/the-views#IFRAME) is a web2py helper function):

```
def generate_map_from_latitude_and_longitude(self, latitude, longitude, _height = '300', _width = '300'):
    try:            
        _src = 'https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=%s,%s&key=%s' % (latitude, longitude, self.API_KEY)

        return IFRAME(_src = _src, _height = _height, _width = _width)
    except Exception as e:
        print e
```

For some reason, including another iframe (with no content, no attributes, etc.) anywhere in the page solves the problem. Any thoughts as to what may be causing the issue?

Comment: `&amp;key` is because of the copy & paste or is it the real code you have?

Comment: The '&amp' seems to be generated by the python function that's used to generate the iframe. I edited the text of the question to include this function.

Comment: try `https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=40.750504,-73.99343899999997&key=my_key` If it works okay the generated function is malformed.

Comment: @Engerlost - I tried using the URL string you suggested, and the same problem persists.

Comment: Try `https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=API_KEY&q=40.750504,-73.99343899999997`

Comment: @Verma - tried your suggestion, and it works. Then, I reverted to the previous variant, and it has started to work as well (without having to resort to the hack of inserting an empty <iframe> into the page). Perhaps there was some issue on Google's end, but I have no idea what happened there. Glad it's functional now, but I'm curious what the issue was to begin with; and more importantly, I'm hoping that the problem does not recur. Thanks to Engerlost and Verma for the suggestions!

Comment: @Boa It's just weird that switching params places works. But as Places need a valid key, the url I gave you worked only it said I need a valid api key... Glad you have it working now!.